# "Загадать загадку" — это допустимая тавтология?

Tags: грамотная-речь, тавтология

В Нацкорпусе нашёл 14 вхождений на разные формы этого выражения. Не много, но употребляется, встретилось и у Достоевского, и у Островского.

Если этой тавтологии всё же следует избегать, на какое простое естественное выражение можно это заменить (скорее всего, поменять глагол)?

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Кузнецова есть даже такой пример:
загадать
1) *что* Предложить загадку или вопрос, требующий разгадки.
*Загадать загадку.

Загадать ребус.*

Исходя из этого — вполне допустимо. То есть загадывать можно разное. Но нельзя сказать, что эта фраза идеальна по звучанию, так как у слов одинаковый корень и префикс.